# jQuery ReplaceWith adding two copies of cloned node

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**I'm using jquery 1.7.2**

I have an jQuery object `copyItem` in which a subset of the contents contains the following html

```
<tr>            
    <td class="command" style="" colspan="3">
        <input type="button" class="insertCommand" value="Add">
    </td>        
</tr>
```

not too complex.

I also have some template html...

```
<table id="itemCommandTemplate">
    <tr>
        <td class="command" style="" colspan="3"><input type="button" class="editCommand" value="Edit"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="deleteCommand">delete</a></td>
        <td class="command" style="display: none" colspan="3"><input type="button" class="saveCommand" value="Save"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="cancelCommand">cancel</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

... that I am cloning with the following jQuery

```
var command = $('#itemCommandTemplate tr').clone(true, true);
```

If I write out the html of command, all appears in order.

I then attempt to replace the original html in copyItem with this cloned copy using

```
copyItem.find('.command').parent('tr').replaceWith(command);
```

after this call, what results is two copies

```
<tr>
    <td class="command" style="" colspan="3"><input type="button" class="editCommand" value="Edit"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="deleteCommand">delete</a></td>
    <td class="command" style="display: none" colspan="3"><input type="button" class="saveCommand" value="Save"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="cancelCommand">cancel</a></td>
    <td class="command" style="" colspan="3"><input type="button" class="editCommand" value="Edit"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="deleteCommand">delete</a></td>
    <td class="command" style="display: none" colspan="3"><input type="button" class="saveCommand" value="Save"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="cancelCommand">cancel</a></td>
</tr>
```

I thought perhaps the `.find` was returning two objects, but the resulting html is correct except for the two nodes inserted. Can't seem to figure it out. If I just replace the html, all looks fine, but I want the events to be attached also.

any clue?

**Edit**

adding full contents of `copyItem`

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 200px">company:</td>
            <td style="width: 100px">campaigns:</td>
            <td style="width: 300px"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="companyName">$5 Dinners</td>
            <td>
                <select class="roleTypeList">
                    <option value="1000">All</option>
                    <option value="1001">Limited</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td rowspan="3" style="text-align: right">
                <input id="zzz" name="zzz" type="hidden" value="insert">
                <div id="zzz" style="">
                    <select size="4" name="zzz" multiple="multiple" id="zzz" class="campaignList" style="width:300px;">
                    </select>
                </div>            
            </td>        
        </tr>          
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">reports:</td>
        </tr>
        <tr> 
            <td colspan="2">
                <input type="checkbox" value="1004" id="PinRptAdd">
                <label for="PinRptAdd">Pin Report</label>
                <input type="checkbox" value="1009" id="CpcAdd">
                <label for="CpcAdd">CPC</label>
                <input type="checkbox" value="1010" id="CpaAdd">
                <label for="CpaAdd">CPA</label>
                <input type="checkbox" value="1011" id="S2cAdd">
                <label for="S2cAdd">S2C</label>                                            
                <input type="checkbox" value="1003" id="LiveDetailsAdd" style="">
                <label for="LiveDetailsAdd" style="">Live Details</label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="command" style="" colspan="3">
                  <input type="button" class="insertCommand" value="Add">
            </td>        
         </tr>    
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: `.parents('tr')` or just `.parent()`.

Comment: note: I believe replace with will replace the whole tag, not just the content. in this case it'll get rid of the <tr></tr> as well

Comment: I tried .parent('tr') and .closest('tr'), both with the same result

Comment: @kennypu, correct, I want the entire tag replaced which is why the template also contains the <tr> tags

Comment: It works here. http://jsfiddle.net/sQbSp/

Comment: @RicardoLohmann, that is also showing two copies, the problem I'm experiencing.

Answer (score 0):

try this instead:

```
copyItem.find('.command').parent().html(command.html());
```

Comment: as I mentioned, I tried that and it works, but it does not copy the events tied to the dom elements

Comment: then for the events, assuming you're using jQuery to bind them, use .live() or .on(), and it should still work.

Comment: If you recommend `.live()` I'm downvoting you

Comment: i'll need to see the dom events, since that is out of scope of the question, but for example, a .click event would be: $('#something').live('click',function(){/*stuff here*/});

Comment: @Alexander i've given both options. we don't know what version of jQuery he is running, thus it is not a bad suggestion. you should give more insightful comments then that.

Comment: You should have asked that

Comment: I don't need to ask that, because I've given both methods.

Comment: I'm actually using `on` `$(".editCommand").on("click", function (e) {...});`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
.replaceWith(command);
```

You can just do

```
.html(command.html());
```